# Why hex-edit is not reversible?

Tags: linux, vi, hex-editors

I've two identical .fit image.

> Linux@Linux:~/imgs/ImageTesting# sha256sum hexd_ss.fit ss.fit
>
> dff6b019b590edb3e9c61c984205c5f49a4064be34feb6207c88dc920aad17e0 
>   hexd_ss.fit
>   dff6b019b590edb3e9c61c984205c5f49a4064be34feb6207c88dc920aad17e0 
>   ss.fit

I've changed one bit of hexd_ss.fit

Linux@Linux:~/imgs/ImageTesting# vi hexd_ss.fit

From

```
0000 0000
```

To

```
0000 0001
```

So I've got two different file size and different hash

```
> Linux@Linux:~/imgs/ImageTesting# ls -l total 9344
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4781261 Jun 16 15:45 hexd_ss.fit
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4781260 Jun 16 15:33 ss.fit
>
```

> Linux@Linux:~/imgs/ImageTesting# sha256sum hexd_ss.fit ss.fit
>
> f3277110043b4170c111fa7d4291aa7df23de68c9e504259ae6158e5133faf1a 
>   hexd_ss.fit
>   dff6b019b590edb3e9c61c984205c5f49a4064be34feb6207c88dc920aad17e0 
>   ss.fit

But when I've changed that bit 0 again, like before, it remain unchanged in size and as well two different hash.

After changing

```
> 0000 0001  to > 0000 0000

Linux@Linux:~/imgs/ImageTesting# ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4781261 Jun 16 15:47 hexd_ss.fit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4781260 Jun 16 15:33 ss.fit
```

Even if I've change two zero bytes to two one bytes the size remain also same. As,

```
0000 1111

Linux@Linux:~/imgs/ImageTesting# ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4781261 Jun 16 15:47 hexd_ss.fit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4781260 Jun 16 15:33 ss.fit
```

So my questions are -

1. Why its not possible to reverse HexEdit ?
2. How or what other way to reverse the edit to origin ?

Comment: The title and key question here are a little strangely worded. Do you simply want to know why the file size changes and then does not change back?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why does flipping a bit change the file size? Perhaps you inadvertently deleted a byte, additionally.

Comment: I mainly want to know how to get back the Hex changed file back to its original one. I used vi with ' :%!xxd '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened my python3.5 binary with `vi python3.5`, then did `:%!xxd`, `:%!xxd -r`, `:wq` ... and ended up with a file that's 1 byte larger.  Note how I didn't even edit anything.  You shall use

```
vi -b <file>
```

to open binary files with `vi`... or they get converted when you open them :P

My python3.5 binary got a `0a` appended to it - a line feed.  After removing this byte, the file was exactly the same as the original again.

Comment: You are right, my mistake was not to use -b switch as binary mode.
while searching why it is so, I found a nice question and answer is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676528/difference-between-text-mode-and-binary-mode-in-c)

Comment: @meAbab  Hm that Q&A is only superficially related, the behavior of translating `lf` to `crlf` as described in that question is OS specific and `vi` doesn't do this.   The appending of `lf` by `vi` is simply how `vi` behaves.  Some more editors behave like that, like `gedit` and `pico`.  But e.g. `mousepad` doesn't.